# True or false: infinite sequence in a compact topological group is dense.

Tags: general-topology, compactness, topological-groups

This is from an exercise in Bredon's Topology and Geometry:

> Let $G$ be a compact topological group (assumed to be Hausdorff). Let $g\in G$ and define $A=\{g^n:n=0,1,2...\}$. Then show that the closure $\bar{A}$ is a topological subgroup.

Note if the assumption of compactness is dropped, then the statement is false. A counterexample is $\mathbb{N}\subset \mathbb{R}$ as additive sets.

Note: if we add the assumption of $G$ being 1st countable, this question is easy to answer.

So, if the set $A$ is finite, then it is a cyclic group and it is already closed. In the infinite case, I can only think of the example of an infinite subgroup of the circle group, which is dense in compact group. I am not sure how to proceed with the proof of this general fact. Any hint will be appreciated.

Comment: Your title and body seem to ask two different questions. It is not in general true that $A$ is dense in $G$ if $G$ is compact and $g$ has infinite order.

Comment: For a simple counterexample of an $A$ which is not dense look at $S^1\times S^1$

Comment: I was thinking of using sequential compactness argument, but I noticed that 1st countability assumption is not included in the definition of topological groups. This leads me to condider density.

Comment: A more general result is that for every subgroup $H$ of a topological group $G$, the closure $\overline{H}$ is a subgroup of $G$.  The group $G$ need not be compact and the subgroup $H$ need not be cyclic. See https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Closure_of_Subgroup_is_Group or Prop. 1.4 in http://www.math.wm.edu/~vinroot/PadicGroups/topgroups.pdf.

Comment: The setting here is that $A$ is just a subset, not necessarily a group.

Comment: Ah, I misread the definition of $A$ as being all integral powers of $g$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a proof which assumes that $G$ is first countable. Since $G$ is compact, there is a subsequence $(g^{n_k})_{k\in\Bbb Z_+}$ of $(g^n)_{n\in\Bbb Z_+}$ which converges to some $a\in G$. Clearly, $a$ is in fact an element of $A$. But then the sequence $(g^{n_k-1}a)_{k\in\Bbb Z_+}$ is a sequence of elements of $A$ which converges to $g^{-1}a$. So, $g^{-1}a\in A$. By the same argument, $(\forall N\in\Bbb N):g^{-N}a\in A$. But then $(g^{-n_k-1}a)_{k\in\Bbb Z_+}$ is a sequence of elements of $A$ which converges to $g^{-1}$ and this proves that $g^{-1}\in A$. By the same argument, $(\forall N\in\Bbb N):g^{-N}\in A$. Can you take it from here?

If you drop the assumption that $G$ is first countable, you can still get the conclusion that you want to get, using nets in the proof, as suggested by Eric Wofsey in the comments.

Comment: We can't assume $a^{-1}\in A$, instead what we can easily show is $A$ closed under action of $g^{-1}$.

Comment: Thanks for answering. My confusion is whether sequential compactness is a valid argument, since $G$ might not be first countable.

Comment: @Berci Sure. I've edited my answer. I hope that everything is correct now.

Comment: @kzkzkzz Every compact topological space is sequentially compact.

Comment: @José $[0,1]^{[0,1]}$ and $\beta\omega$ are two of the many examples of spaces that are compact but not sequentially compact

Comment: @AlessandroCodenotti Right. I made a mistake. I thought that every compact topological space is sequentially compact. In fact, in general, neither of these properties implies the other one.

Comment: Maybe in this question we do need to assume 1st countability.

Comment: I don't have a copy of the book at hand right now. Perhaps the the author is assuming that. I don't know.

Comment: No the author did not assume this.

Comment: The argument works if you just use nets instead of sequences.

Comment: @EricWofsey Sure! I missed that. I shall edit my answer. Thank you.

Comment: How do you know that the subnet of $g^n$ doesn't contain the identity element?  Possibly infinitely many times?

Comment: I don't know. Is that a problem?

Comment: You need to know that $n_k - 1 \ge 0$.

Comment: Otherwise you don't know that $g^{n_k-1} a \in A$.

Comment: But $(g^{n_k})_{k\in\Bbb Z_+}$ is a subsequence of $(g^n)_{n\in\Bbb Z_+}$ and therefore $\lim_{k\to\infty}n_k=\infty$.

Comment: It's not a subsequence.  It is a subnet.

Comment: Right! I will have t tink about that.

Answer (score 1):

Multiplication by an element of $G$ is a homeomorphism of $G$, so $g\bar A = \overline{gA}$.  Also $\bar A \bar A \subset \bar A$, and all elements of $\bar A$ commute with each other (I think this proof works: [Let $G$ be a compact group. If $\{a^n\}_{n \in \mathbb{Z}}$ is dense in $G$, then $G$ is abelian.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1408227/let-g-be-a-compact-group-if-an-n-in-mathbbz-is-dense-in-g-the/1408249#1408249)).

Case 1: $1 \in g\bar A$.  Then $g^{-1} \in \bar A$, and we are done.

Case 2: $1 \notin g \bar A$.  Then there exists an open set $N \ni 1$ such that $N \cap g\bar A = \emptyset$.  Thus $(g\bar A) \bar A \subset g \bar A$, and hence for any $x \in g\bar A$ we have that $x \bar A \cap N = \emptyset$.

Now $\{x N:x \in \bar A\}$ is an open cover for $\bar A$.  We show it has no empty subcover.  Given elements $x_1,\dots,x_n \in \bar A\setminus\{1\} = g\bar A$, see that for $x_k^{-1} x_1 \cdots x_n = x_1 \cdots x_{k-1} x_{k+1} \cdots x_n \in g\bar A$.  Thus $N \cap x_k^{-1} x_1 \cdots x_n \bar A = \emptyset$.  Thus $x_1 \cdots x_n \notin x_k N$.  Therefore $x_1\cdots x_n \notin N \cup x_1 N \cup \dots \cup x_n N$.
Thus Case 2 leads to a contradiction.

Comment: But this proof https://math.stackexchange.com/q/452375 is much better in my opinion.